# Sorting SQLite items alphebetically regardless of case?

Tags: iphone, sqlite, uitableview

I am retrieving items from a SQLite database and displaying them in a UITableview,  I am using the following SQL command to get the information.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Name FROM Food
```

Everything works fine except I notice that uppercase items come sorted first, then lowercase items, which messes up the whole alphabetical setup that I am trying to accomplish.  I have looked into various SQL commands, but I couldn't find anything that would change this. I am new to working with databases, so any advice would be welcomed.

Example of problem:

- Apple
- Basket
- Cheese
- beets

What I would like:

- Apple
- Basket
- beets
- Cheese

Answer (score 1, accepted):

order by **lowercase**:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Name
FROM Food
ORDER BY lower(Name)
```

Comment: Brilliant. Don't know how I missed that.  Thanks a lot manji.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the built-in NOCASE function for case insensitive matching,
but it works only for ASCII characters.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Name
FROM Food
ORDER BY Name ASC COLLATE NOCASE
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use `SELECT DISTINCT Name FROM Food ORDER BY Name ASC`?